# Regarding Dependency Injection

Tags: spring

```
interface Car {
    public void tyres();
}

class BMW implements Car {
    public void tyres() {
        System.out.println("BMW");
    }
}

class HMW implements Car {
    public void tyres() {
        System.out.println("HMW");
    }
}

public class DependencyInjection {
private Car car;

    public void draw() {
         this.car.tyres();
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public static void tyres1(Car c) {
        c.tyres();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new BMW();
        tyres1(car);//point 1
        DependencyInjection dep=new DependencyInjection();
        dep.setCar(car);//point2
        dep.draw();
    }
}
```

I want some clarification what is advantage we have  creating dependency injection at point 1 and point2.Please explain me in detail as i am new to spring???

Comment: At point1 I'd rather call it a normal polymorphic method call than a dependency injection. You may want to read the [Wikipedia article on dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 3):

This is not a Spring specific design principle, and it's hard to grasp in the snippet you've provided which does not have notable separated pieces, but becomes more helpful as systems grow.

By removing the reference to a concrete class you eliminate "type coupling" which means that the internal class can remain "closed": it won't have to change if the implementation changes of the involved class and the client code can use different ways to adapt as needed without the inner class needing to change or be aware of the implementation. This also helps ensure that the method body within the class is focusing on its role and its specific job rather than being getting tangled in with any other implementation (which helps in clearly defining what should be considered part of an API).

You should also read about the concept of SOLID classes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

The most immediate benefit in my experience is that it also allows for far more complete, isolated unit tests which is very important if that is part of your development process (which is recommended also as systems grow).

Answer (score 0):

Actually what Dependency Injection does that part is done by your code:

```
 Car car = new BMW();
```

Dependency Injection feature helps you to mentioned dependency as configuration and Framework actually does the rest Injection of Object to references.